# chartjs 4.2.1 change datalabes style vue

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, chart.js-datalabels

I'm using Vue and ChartJS, and I want to change datalabes style.

I have 3 datalabes, I want to change second label style to bold from normal.

### What i tried - 1

```js
plugins: {
    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    datalabels: {
        formatter: function (value, context) {
            if (context.dataIndex === 1) {
                var ctx = context.chart.ctx;
                ctx.font = "bold 20px 'Noto Sans Kr', sans-serif";
                ctx.fillStyle = "#333";
                console.log(ctx.fontWeight);
            }
            return value + "원";
        },
    },
},
```

### What i tried - 2

```js
plugins: {
    legend: {
        display: false,
    },
    tooltip: {
        enabled: false,
    },
    datalabels: {
        formatter: function (value, context) {
            if (context.dataIndex === 1) {
                return {
                    text: value,
                    style : {
                        weight: 'bold'
                    }
                }
            }
            return value + "원";
        },
    },
},
```

Number 2 way return's text is **[object object]** so i can't confirm thT style works well.

Please help me to change databases individual style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the font, you should implement the scriptable options for the `font` options and not the `formatter` one.

```
  datalabels: {
    font: (context) => context.dataIndex === 1 ? ({weight: 'bold'}) : undefined 
    formatter: (value) => value + "원"
  },
```

Comment: inside of weight of font 's function does not working.
I changed like this.
</br>
---
datalabels: {
    font: {
       weight: (context) => {
                                console.log(context);
                                return context.dataIndex === 1 ? "bold" : undefined;
                            },
    },
    formatter: (value) => value + "원"
  },
---

but console.log never show...

Comment: my fault. the font options is scriptable, not the single properties. I'm going to update the answer

Comment: try now with new code or have a look to the codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/wvYoWgW Let me know if it's working to you as well

Comment: thank you! it works! and i have a question. if i do like this.
```
    datalabels: {
            anchor: 'end',
            align: 'end',
            offset: 0,
            labels: {
              title: {
                font: {
                  size: 12,
                },
              },
            },
            font: (context) => (isMiddle(context) ? { weight: 'bold' } : undefined),
            formatter: (value) => value + '원',
          },
```

bold doesn't work. but if i remove 
```
    font: {
                  size: 12,
                },
```
it works. why?

Comment: it should work. Can you create a codepen to reproduce the your use case?

Comment: https://codepen.io/sori-sodong/pen/LYgbJVY
In this js code, if i remove // codes, it doesnt work well. TT..I want to know the reason

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253269/discussion-between-helpme-and-user2057925).